# Android EditText color change destroys margins

Tags: java, android, android-layout, android-edittext

I have a set of edittexts in a relative layout displayed in a vertical line. By default they have a tiny margin between them although I don't have any margin set. When I change the background color of one of them its bottom margin is lost and the space is shortened to what I assume is the tiny top margin of the edittext below it. I tried to use `setPadding()`, but with no result. The only thing that worked was `setBackground()`, but that also changes the color to the original one.

Comment: you can add your code here? That might give a better idea.

Comment: I use this to change the color : `tari.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#2aff00"));` and this to revert to the original background which I had saved in a Drawable at the beginning :`tari.setBackground(backs[0]);`

Comment: `setPadding()` will add space internally. Why don't you simply set a margin for the EditText if you want one?

Comment: I'd do that if I could get rid of its default margin, I don't want the EditText to move on the screen at all.

Comment: By default, EditText has a background assigned to it. Define your custom background resource, which will invalidate the default one and then try assigning margin.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of setPadding try setting margin in xml to the Edittexts. Incase you need to set margin by code you will have to modify layout params of the edit texts.

Setting margin in XML should solve your problem.

Comment: I tried to set it now to 1dp, but it also has its default one and you can see the edittext moving on the screen when I change the color. The thing is I want it to be completely stationary, so I'd set a margin if I could get rid of its default margin then.

Answer (score 0):

This works for me:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:alpha="0.9">

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/editText1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:background="#8A084B"
    android:ems="10" />

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/editText2"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_below="@+id/editText1"
    android:background="@android:color/black"
    android:ems="10" >

    <requestFocus />
</EditText>

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/editText3"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_below="@+id/editText2"
    android:background="@android:color/darker_gray"
    android:ems="10" />
```

And with some margins between them:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:alpha="0.9">

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/editText1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_marginBottom="2dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="2dp"
    android:background="#8A084B"
    android:ems="10" />

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/editText2"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_below="@+id/editText1"
    android:layout_marginBottom="2dp"
    android:background="@android:color/black"
    android:ems="10" >

    <requestFocus />
</EditText>

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/editText3"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_below="@+id/editText2"
    android:background="@android:color/darker_gray"
    android:ems="10" />
```

If you want, you can fix them with the id's and `android:layout_alignTop=` or Bottom. I hope it helps.